# Is it possible to build DRAM out of discrete transistors and capacitors?

Tags: mosfet, ram

Is it possible to build DRAM out of discrete MOSFET transistors and capacitors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, but not practical.  As a learning experience it could be useful, however.

For the main memory array you will need one FET and one cap per bit.  So for any even marginally useful DRAM you will need a thousand or more FETs and Caps.  On top of that you'll need the proper circuits to read and write the memory array.

Here is a [good article from the Smithsonian museum on DRAM design](http://smithsonianchips.si.edu/ice/cd/MEMORY97/SEC07.PDF).

Comment: Will the refresh times be respectable?

Comment: The cap size determines the physical size and the refresh times.  Change as you see fit.

Comment: @Saad: The maximum time between refreshes would probably be pretty long, since the bus capacitance would probably be much higher than for a monolithic DRAM, and to compensate the cell capacitors would also have to be correspondingly larger than those in a monolithic DRAM in order to allow reliable operation at any refresh interval. Making the capacitors twice as big as the absolute minimum would probably allow a relatively generous refresh time while at worst doubling the amount of current required. A potential problem with normal MOSFETs is that they generally tie the subtrate to the source.

Comment: @Saad: Trying the substrate to the source has two bad effects: (1) while a MOSFET with isolated source and drain can have either potential be higher than the other by a significant voltage without conducting, the source-substrate connection creates an unwanted diode; (2) isolated-substrates have substantial capacitance between the substrate and both source and drain.  If the substrate could stay at ground, this would be beneficial.  Alas, however, the source-substrate connection means the capacitance will connect the storage cap and the bus.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, it is. Take a look at the [Atanasoff-Berry Computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atanasoff%E2%80%93Berry_Computer), which used capacitors mounted on a rotating drum to store data. No MOSFETs, though — strictly mechanical switching.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest "DRAM" cell would be a large enough electrolytic capacitor alone. You can charge it from some power source of the suitable voltage and it will hold its "bit" for some time (voltmeter could show). The capacitor will lose the information while "reading the bit", or spontaneously over time, but the real DRAM cells also are not free from this problem.

Probably some extra components would be good to charge, discharge the capacitor and some MOSFET circuit to indicate if it is charged or not. A properly designed MOSFET circuit can "keep reading" the state of the electrolytic capacitor maybe even for days without discharging it.